# C# + Blazor - EditForms/Context, FluentValidation and Virtualize combined

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluentvalidation

Sometimes you just have to know when to ask for help. I have been struggling with a solution on this for weeks and could use ideas how to resolve.

EditForms and FluentValidation (for shorthand I will call it EFV) in Blazor can be a fantastic harmony. But not when Virtualize is involved. You use Virtualize to make it an easier time handling 1000s of rows in a table but the way EFV works together is that the EditForm needs to be rendered for validation to be easily run.

Something Virtualize does not do as in the name, it virtualizes. Only rendering what you need to see.

So as a result, when you validate all of the rows it in truth only does 20 rows out of 200.

I have simplified it down to a very basic level. Below is the Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using EditForms_And_Tables.Components;
@using EditForms_And_Tables.Models;
@using EditForms_And_Tables.Utils;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
@using FluentValidation;
@using EditForms_And_Tables.Validators;

<div style="height:500px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <Virtualize Items="@_people" Context="item" ItemSize="38">
        <div class="row">
            <EditForm EditContext="@_editContexts[item.GUID]" @ref="_editForms[item.GUID]">
                <FluentValidationValidator ValidatorType=typeof(Validators.PersonValidator) />
                <InputText @bind-Value=item.Name class="form-control" id="Name" />
                <InputNumber @bind-Value=item.Age class="form-control" id="Age" />
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

<button type="button" @onclick="EventUtil.AsNonRenderingEventHandler(OnFormSubmit)">Check Validation</button>

@code
{
    private List<Person> _people = new();
    private Dictionary<string, EditForm> _editForms = new();
    private Dictionary<string, EditContext> _editContexts = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        //This is the test data. It is randomized to produce validation errors
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            var person = new Person();
            _people.Add(person);
            _editContexts[person.GUID] = new EditContext(person);
        }
    }

    private async Task OnFormSubmit()
    {
        var invalidRows = 0;

        //Loops through each person and validates the editcontext
        //Tallies up the invalid rows
        foreach (var person in _people)
        {
            if (!_editContexts.ContainsKey(person.GUID))
            {
                _editContexts[person.GUID] = new EditContext(person);
            }

            var result = _editContexts[person.GUID].Validate();
            invalidRows += result ? 0 : 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(invalidRows);
    }
}
```

Along with the FluentValidationValidator class I am currently using

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using FluentValidation.Results;

namespace EditForms_And_Tables.Validators
{
    // Sourced from https://blazor-university.com/forms/writing-custom-validation/

    public class FluentValidationValidator : ComponentBase
    {
        [CascadingParameter]
        public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public Type ValidatorType { get; set; }

        private IValidator Validator;
        private ValidationMessageStore ValidationMessageStore;
        [Inject]
        private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            //Configures the validatortype and editcontext per change. Also rejects invalid values
            EditContext previousEditContext = EditContext;
            Type previousValidatorType = ValidatorType;

            await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);

            if (EditContext == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(FluentValidationValidator)} must be placed within an {nameof(EditForm)}");
            }

            if (ValidatorType == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(ValidatorType)} must be specified.");
            }

            if (!typeof(IValidator).IsAssignableFrom(ValidatorType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{ValidatorType.Name} must implement {typeof(IValidator).FullName}");
            }

            if (ValidatorType != previousValidatorType)
            {
                ValidatorTypeChanged();
            }

            if (EditContext != previousEditContext)
            {
                EditContextChanged();
            }
        }

        public void ValidatorTypeChanged()
        {
            Validator = (IValidator)ServiceProvider.GetService(ValidatorType);
        }

        public void EditContextChanged()
        {
            //Sets up the events and message store for the validation
            ValidationMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(EditContext);
            HookUpEditContextEvents();
        }

        private void HookUpEditContextEvents()
        {
            EditContext.OnValidationRequested += ValidationRequested;
            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += FieldChanged;
        }

        async void ValidationRequested(object sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Clears the validation store and runs the validation against the object
            ValidationMessageStore.Clear();
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext<object>(EditContext.Model);
            ValidationResult result = await Validator.ValidateAsync(validationContext);
            AddValidationResult(EditContext.Model, result);
        }

        void AddValidationResult(object model, ValidationResult validationResult)
        {
            //Adds the validation results to the message store
            foreach (ValidationFailure error in validationResult.Errors)
            {
                var fieldIdentifier = new FieldIdentifier(model, error.PropertyName);
                ValidationMessageStore.Add(fieldIdentifier, error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            EditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }

        async void FieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Retrieves the field, clears its message store and validates against the model
            FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier = args.FieldIdentifier;
            ValidationMessageStore.Clear(fieldIdentifier);

            var propertiesToValidate = new string[] { fieldIdentifier.FieldName };
            var fluentValidationContext =
                new ValidationContext<object>(
                    instanceToValidate: fieldIdentifier.Model,
                    propertyChain: new FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyChain(),
                    validatorSelector: new FluentValidation.Internal.MemberNameValidatorSelector(propertiesToValidate)
                );

            ValidationResult result = await Validator.ValidateAsync(fluentValidationContext);

            AddValidationResult(fieldIdentifier.Model, result);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have been trying to achieve (I do not know if it is possible with the EFV) is the ability to validate all 200 rows regardless of rendering and when you scroll down they already have their errors highlighted. Originally I had hoped looping through all, validating and storing the results would have worked but sadly it did not.

So what I wish for is an answer so I can learn from all this as it will make me a better Blazor developer if I can pass this. And if it cannot be done with EFV...what can be done instead to validate all the rows?

I am happy to assist any way possible to help resolve this issue and really appreciate any help offered :)

Comment: If I read this correctly, you're trying to pull unqualified data in from a source into the virtualize component and apply an `EditContext` to each row so you can validate the information and present that validation to the user to fix.   If so, then I humbly suggest you're struggling to solve the problem because you're design is flawed and you're using the wrong tool set.

Comment: Maybe, pull in the full data set and then provide a list of records with errors that need fixing.  Only allow moving on once all the errors are fixed and saved.  You need to put together a real [mre] to get any meaningful answer.

Comment: Maybe you can provide me an insight on how to make it more MRE? I will not lie I have never heard of the term before and I am not sure how I can make it more MRE considering how little there is to the project right now.

Comment: This is a problem not by my design. It is something I have volunteered to help resolve as they could not. I agree that as it stands it does not look favourable for a solution.

I personally think that if they abandon focus on making "industry standard" it could easily be done as I managed to achieve it myself. But they wish to use EditContexts etc as it is more "industry standard".

I would like to look into this as an exercise how to push my skills further

Comment: [In my view] MRE means I can take the code presented in the question and build an example project from it that demonstrates the problem.  I can use that the generate a solution.  Can I do that from your code?  No, there's too much opaque context, I'm struggling to understand the code.  Producing an MRE in this case is not easy.  I sympathise.

Comment: On "Industry Standard", what's that really meant to mean.  Following good clean coding practices is far more important that trying to jump through hoops backwards trying to use set of components that weren't designed to be used in the context in which you are trying to use them  Someone has a design in their head they don't want to surrender.

Comment: Any answer I would provide would be the same as yours - rewrite it.  That's probably the advice of other answerer's on here.  No one else has commented or provided an answer which is probably a good indicator.

Comment: [Polite] If you want some ammo - What is a `StateHasChangedWrapper`? That's definitely not "Industry Standard" and looks like a kludge to fix rendering problems caused by poor design elsewhere.

Comment: Okay I think I can refactor the code to be simpler for that context. I will add comments to for this. I really appreciate the clarity on that and will strive to do better

Comment: Honestly I do sometimes have to scream into a pillow when the words "Industry Standards", "That's not what Microsoft does" or "Everyone's using this nuget" sort of approaches are taking. Just leads to lazy coding. I think I will address them about this today

Comment: To be blunt it has only been up for 12 hours. For something of this complexity and something I daftly did not make comprehensible, I would understand there being no reply

Oh that is something they kept in. It is to allow partial re-rendering of content on screen. It is not really poor design more an old fashioned way of rendering. Though if you have a more streamlined way of updating the value inside I am all ears to that